# why there's a difference with the number of listed items between opensea and in-app marketplace

Tags: nft, metaplex

I am trying to build an in-app marketplace, such as stepN has.

stepN marketplace - https://m.stepn.com/

While I am researching how the stepN marketplace is built, I found something curious.

As I know, opensea uses metaplex auction house to list the NFTs. and so does the stepN marketplace.

So both them are escrowless, and on-chain.

I found that some of the items are both listed on the stepN marketplace and the opensea, but some of them are not.

I know we cannot upload the NFT both in the opensea and the magic eden at the same time, since magic eden is an escrow program.

But why some of them are both listed on the stepN marketplace and the opensea, but some of them are not?

Is it because stepN uses off-chain partially? what is happening behind the scene?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know OpenSea list all the items that belongs into a correct set **[Metaplex Certified Collection (MCC)](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/certified-collections)**. So it should grab and list all the NFTs that your collection has.

Sadly, I don't know how is the OpenSea algorithm that fetch the NFTs from an collection and how much time waits to fetch again the NFTs from a collection in order to detect new added NFTs.

So the main issue on why there are some NFTs that doesnt appear can be because the NFT doesnt have a collection attached to it or the Market didnt fetch the new NFTs that are added into the collection.

The fixes are: adding the NFTs into the collection or waiting till the market fetch the newly added NFTs respectively (this can take some time normally)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it. It makes sense to wait until the opensea market fetches in-app marketplace's listed items. But I am still curious of one thing. I ordered stepN marketplace's NFT shoe in latest order. but latest listed item both listed in the marketplace and the opensea, whereas older listed item only showed in the marketplace. there's still some inconsistency.. so it seems that opensea does not fetch all the items even if the item has been listed long time ago.. what do you think of it?

Comment: A good way to try to get those NFTs listed on those Markets is doing a reset of the collection field. Get all NFTs that doesnt appear on markets, change its collection and then change it again to the old collection and wait till appear. I cant give you an answer on why old items doesnt appear because I dont have access to OpenSea nor stepn code.

Comment: I tried several times in which the way you suggested, but none of the results are found. (some of them ofcourse listed both on marketplace and the opensea). The way which I tried is that, go to https://m.stepN.com and reordered the items from the latest, using the top right filter option, and searched the NFT id number on the opensea (activation code is not required). then some of them are found, some of them are not. and I tested some newly listed item are listed on opensea, whereas some older listed item are not.

Comment: Can you share an NFT id that is not being detected on any of both Markets and one that is detected without issues?

Comment: https://opensea.io/assets/solana/J1HLu5ukmw3HQVnrTaxBZzt6Ns2NDMuJjC1cNssPFpHy

this is the one both listed on the stepN marketplace and the opensea.

Comment: 754192241 this is only listed on the stepN in app marketplace (opensea not found)

Comment: the NFT listed on OpenSea doesnt have a Metaplex Certified Collection attached to its onchain metadata, so your OpenSea listing is not using the MCC method to fetch the NFTs.

Comment: omg.. how can we check if the opensea listed item is MCC attached?

Comment: so to wrap-up, the reason why there's a discrepancy btw the in-app marketplace and the opensea, is that stepN uploads nfts without mcc, so opensea selectively fetches items from the stepN marketplace? And if stepN attaches mcc to all its nfts, and opensea would succesfully fetches all the items if we wait some amount of time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247438/discussion-between-wrathiontbp-and-koo).